# If h:A→B, g:B→C and f:B→C are three functions ,and g◦h =f◦h, then g=f.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is the following statement necessarily true? Provide a proof or a counterexample. 
“If h:A→B, g:B→C and f:B→C are three functions ,and g◦h =f◦h, then g=f.”

My attempt:
No it is not true.

let $h:Z→Z$, h(x) = $x$
    $g:Z→N$,  g(x) = $x^2+1$
    $f:Z→N$. f(x) = $|x|$

g◦h =  $g:N → Z$, g(h(x)) = g(x) = $x^2+1$ and f◦h = $f:N→Z$, f(h(x)) = f(x) = |x|.

Therefore f is not equal to g.

Is this correct? I don't really know how to do this problem.

Comment: You don't have $g \circ h = f \circ h$ to begin with.  If you think it's false, you need to start with an example doing this but where $g \neq f$.

Comment: You cannot choose $h = x$ for the reason that your assumption is then that $g=f$, what you are trying to show does not hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving a counter example with functions defined on "very small sets". I usually find it easier to cook up a counter example in these simpler settings.

For example, let $A := \{1\}, B := \{1,2,3\}$ and $C := B$. Let $h : A \to B$ be given by $h(1) = 1$. Then, consider the functions $f,g : B \to C$ given respectively by the rules
\begin{align*}
f(1) = 1,\quad f(2) = 2, \quad f(3) = 3,\\
g(1) = 1, \quad g(2) = 3, \quad g(3) = 2.
\end{align*}
Clearly, $f$ and $g$ are distinct functions but 
$$
1 = (f \circ h)(x) = (g \circ h)(x)
$$
for all $x \in A$.